# How to make a Google BigQuery table from CSV that contain a column with mixed datatypes?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I am trying to use BigQuery to load data from CSV files that I have stored in GCS.

One of the columns in the CSV files `Mfg Part Number` has some values that are integers and some values that are strings. For example: `M47CH232`, `320034`, `G342`.

I have defined my custom schema and this field has the following settings:

```
...
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "Mfg_Part_Number",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
...
```

I loaded a small table with 10 rows to validate that the `Mfg Part Number` column is showing up correctly. I found some strange inconsistencies that I am struggling to understand:

***Some* of the integer values from `Mfg Part Number` have `0` added to the front of the value.**

Here is an example of what I am seeing in my CSV vs what I am seeing in the Google BigQuery preview:

**csv**:

```
Mfg Part Number
...
7550787599
66253752170
5539561582
44033
...
```

**BigQuery Preview**

```
Mfg Part Number
...
07550787599
66253752170
05539561582
44033
...
```

Also, on a separate but related issue, I have another column that I indicated as `STRING` in the schema, and the numbers that are all of the form `123456` are all displaying as `123456.0` in BigQuery even though they are of type string.

Can anyone help explain why I might be seeing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating your CSV file with a software like Excel and this seems to be the reason why your fields are in the wrong format.

Before uploading your file I suggest to open it whit a software like notepad to verify your data is in the correct format.

Also verify that your CSV file is using encoding UTF-8 [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv_encoding